# How do I have user input a long and then print that long accurately in C?

Tags: c, cs50

I am trying to create a program that has the user input a credit card sized number for the CS50 problem set 1.

After prompting the user to enter in the card number, I wrote a print function to make sure that I have the correct number stored. However, the output is always a number that is way off from the number I input. I have messed around trying to change the `long` to a `long long` or a `long long int`.

What should I try to get my code to correctly store the number I input?

Code:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>

int question(void);

int main(void)
{
    long n = question();
    printf("%ld\n", n);
}

int question(void)
{
    long n;
    do {
        n = get_long("Number: ");
    } while (n < 1000000000000 || n > 9999999999999999);
    return n;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./credit
Number: 1234567890123456
1015724736
```

Comment: `int question(void);` Why `int` if you want a `long`?

Comment: 'int question(void)' ?'

Comment: Enable compiler warnings to identify all sorts of things .. should be taught during the first lecture on invoking a compiler IMOHO.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are saving a long in `n`, your function is returning an int.
Just changing the return type will do the trick.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>

long question(void);

int main(void)
{
    long n= question();
    printf("%ld\n", n);
}


long question(void)
{
    long  n;
    do
    {
        n = get_long("Number: ");
    }
    while (n < 1000000000000 || n > 9999999999999999);
    return n;
}
```